# Growth rate of expectation of exponential random variable given no arrival so far (when is the nuclear war happening?)

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian

I heard an interview in which the participants were discussing how long they expect it to be until a nuclear war happens. That made me wonder the following:

It's well known that an exponential random variable $X$ with parameter $\lambda$ is memoryless, i.e. $E[X | X > t] = E[X] + t = \frac{1}{\lambda} + t$. (Of course, the incidence of nuclear war is not a memoryless process, but leave that aside)

However, what happens if we don't know $\lambda$ but have a prior over it instead? Define $f(t) = E_{\lambda, X \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)} \left[ X | X > t\right] -t$, so that if the prior is a point mass on $\lambda_0$ we just have $f(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda_0}$.

It seems clear that for any prior with full support, $f(t)$ should grow, but how fast? $O(\log t)$, $O(\sqrt t)$, something else? Does the asymptotic growth rate depend on the prior or do all priors end up with the same growth rate eventually?

Edit: This doesn't seem particularly easy, so I'd also be curious about results for particular priors. A gamma prior is conjugate to the exponential, but in this case you don't get a "full" observation, so it's not clear to me if that's relevant.

Comment: Have you tried working through a particular example (other than the point mass)? My intuition is that $f(t)$ should be constant regardless of chosen prior, based on memorylessness.

Comment: See angryavian's answer below for an expression for the answer. My intuition was that it should grow, based on similarity to a geometric random variable, which is also memoryless. I was thinking about drawing a sample from a geometric random variable by flipping a possibly unfair coin until I get heads.  If my initial expectation (by integrating over my prior) is that it will take 2 flips, I'll be pretty sure it's unfair after 100 tails, rather than just expecting to wait another 2 flips. I'm not sure if that intuition transfers directly to the exponential case though.

Comment: I mean, informally I'd be pretty sure it's not fair after 100 flips as well. But *mathematically,* if it really is fair, whether or not I've flipped it once, 10 times, 100 times, or even $10^{100}$ times without a head, I still expect to wait two more flips to see a head past what I've already flipped. That's how memorylessness works.

Comment: But if I have a prior over the parameter, I can compute a posterior given the information I have. I'm basically asking what exactly the effect of considering a prior is on memorylessness.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're saying. If I understand you correctly, we're really changing from one distribution to another by updating the prior to the posterior, where the update is based on the fact that we haven't seen an arrival (or a nuclear war) in the first $t$ units of time, so we wouldn't expect memorylessness because our distribution changed partway through.

Comment: Not only that, but the "failure of memorylessness" really inheres in *how much longer we subjectively estimate*: since the true value of $\lambda$ is some fixed constant (if we're using the exponential model), the **actual** extra arrival time is still memoryless. But our *expected prediction* of the extra arrival time may change based on our subjective prior estimates for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to angryavian's answer, I got a weak general result, and did a calculation for the specific case of a gamma prior. To start with:

\begin{equation}
f(t) = \frac{E\left[\frac{1}{\lambda} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t} \right]}{E\left[\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t}\right]}
= \frac{\mathscr{L}\left(p\left(\lambda) / \lambda\right)\right)}{\mathscr{L}\left(p\left(\lambda\right)\right)}
\end{equation}

Where $p(\lambda)$ is the pdf of the prior, and $\mathscr{L}(\cdot)$ is the Laplace transform. In looking for information on the ratio of Laplace transforms, I found Lemma 4 of [Yang and Tian (2017)](https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-017-1591-9), which states:

> Let the functions $A$, $B$ be defined on $(0,\infty)$ such that their Laplace transforms
> exist with $B(t) \neq 0$ for all $t > 0$. Then the function
> \begin{equation}
> x \to U(x) = \frac{\int_0^\infty A(t) \mathrm{e}^{-xt} dt}{\int_0^\infty B(t) \mathrm{e}^{-xt} dt}
> \end{equation}
> is decreasing (increasing) on $(0,\infty)$ if $A/B$ is increasing (decreasing) on $(0,\infty)$.

In this case, $A(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}p(\lambda)$, and $B(\lambda) = p(\lambda)$. The ratio of these quantities is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ which is strictly decreasing on $(0, \infty)$, which tells us that $f(t)$ is increasing, regardless of the choice of prior! (provided the laplace transform of $p(\lambda) / \lambda$ exists)

For a specific example, using a gamma prior (which is conjugate to the exponential distribution) with shape $\alpha > 1$ (the calculation below doesn't converge if
$\alpha \leq 1$) and rate $\beta$, we get:

\begin{align*}
\mathscr{L}\left(p(\lambda)\right) &= \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(t + \beta)^\alpha}\\
\mathscr{L}\left(p(\lambda)/\lambda\right) &= \int_t^\infty \mathscr{L}(p)(s) ds\\
&= \int_t^\infty \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(s + \beta)^\alpha} ds \\
&= \left[\frac{-\beta^\alpha}{(\alpha - 1)(s + \beta)^{\alpha - 1}}\right]_{t}^\infty\\
&= \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\alpha - 1)(t + \beta)^{\alpha - 1}}
\end{align*}

This gives:

\begin{equation}
f(t) = \frac{t + \beta}{\alpha - 1}
\end{equation}

So how much longer we have to wait for an exponentially distributed event with a gamma prior scales linearly with how long we've waited already.

Comment: I had tried the exponential distribution ($\alpha=1$) which was why I ended my post with the misgiving that my work was not correct. "Regardless of the choice of prior" might need to be qualified with the condition of the lemma "their Laplace transforms exist," as you noted for the cases $\alpha \le 1$. Do you have any thoughts on what exactly fails in the $\alpha \le 1$ case? I don't think it is implying that $E_{\lambda, X} [X \mid X > t]$ does not exist; I think it is just making one of my steps invalid or something.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer.

Regarding the $\alpha \le 1$ case, just leaving $t$ aside even I'm pretty sure the expectation $E_\lambda[X]$ doesn't exist. It requires you to integrate $\lambda^{\alpha - 2}\mathrm{e}^{-\beta \lambda}$ which I imagine doesn't work for the same reason that you need $\alpha > 0$ for the normal gamma integral.

In terms of actual meaning, marginalizing out the prior gives such a heavy tailed distribution that its expectation is infinite. In the $\alpha \le 1$ case the ordinary intuition of having $\alpha - 1$ observations also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Nice work finding that lemma!

Answer (score 1):

Some partial thoughts, possibly with errors:

I assume the Bayesian model is
\begin{align}
\lambda &\sim \text{some distribution on the positive reals}
\\
X \mid \lambda &\sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda)
\end{align}

I saw you changed the definition of $f$ slightly when editing your question. The way you define it subtly affects how things turn out.

1. If you define the term in $f(t)$ as $E_{\lambda, X}[X \mid X > t]$, then this becomes
   $$\frac{E[X \mathbf{1}_{X > t}]}{E[\mathbf{1}_{X > t}]}
   = \frac{E[E[X \mathbf{1}_{X > t} \mid \lambda]]}{E[E[\mathbf{1}_{X > t} \mid \lambda]]}
   = \frac{E[(t + 1/\lambda) e^{-\lambda t}]}{E[e^{-\lambda t}]}
   = t + \frac{E[e^{-\lambda t} / \lambda]}{E[e^{-\lambda t}]}.$$
2. This is different from $E_\lambda [E[X \mid \lambda, \{X > t\}]]$, which is
   $$E_\lambda[t +\frac{1}{\lambda}] = t + E_\lambda[1/\lambda].$$

I assume you meant option 1 (since in the case of option 2, $f$ is just a constant function). It's not clear to me how $f(t) = \frac{E[e^{-\lambda t} / \lambda]}{E[e^{-\lambda t}]}$ varies with $t$ (it is not even clear to me that it should grow with $t$). In fact, in some cases $E[e^{-\lambda t} / \lambda]$ may not even be finite, so perhaps there is something wrong with my work.

Comment: I did indeed mean option 1, I only noticed my mistake after I posted. It's very bizarre to imagine a prior where my expectation shrinks with time! I think in the short run you can achieve it with a bimodal prior, where there's a large amount of mass on one very large value of lambda, and the rest on a very small value, so once there fails to be an arrival for a while the probability mass will migrate to the small value of lambda.

Comment: @DavisYoshida Ah, I see your intuition now, something to do with how the probability mass of the prior needs to decay as one approaches infinity.

Comment: Looks like there aren't any sneakily constructed priors. The ratio is always monotone! (see my self-answer)

Comment: (Non-strictly increasing, so maybe there's some prior which leads to recovering memorylessness)